# Mounted samba drive with Java but the drive label isn't updating in file explorer?

Tags: java, windows, samba

I'm working on a Java GUI application that can unmount and mount Samba shares to a specific letter drive. The drives are successfully unmounted and mounted when the user selects, however the drive label (the display name of drive) is not updating in windows file explorer.

I'm using the `ProcessBuilder` to execute the command and I don't run into this issue when I just use the windows CMD myself but the command I run is identical.

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( "net",
        "use",
        "T:",
        "\\\\" + SERVER_NAME + "\\" + SHARE_NAME + "\\" + FOLDER,
        "/USER:" + USERNAME,
        PASSWORD,
        "/PERSISTENT:NO"
        );
```

The really strange thing is that when I open the file browser that's built into my applications gui for the **first time**, it shows the drive with the correct label, even though windows file explorer shows the old label. This is only the case when you open it for the first time though and then it will not show any new drive labels.

I'm guessing this is more of a windows specific thing that I'm dealing with and not an issue with the code. Any ideas how I can force windows to refresh the label or any other ideas?

Update - I discovered that if I restart `explorer.exe` process in task manager it will refresh the label when I reopen the file explorer. I don't want to do this in my application because it refreshes the entire windows desktop interface but it might provide some insight.

Update 2 - I also noticed that if I `Thread.sleep()` for 5 seconds between unmounting the initial drive and mounting the selected drive the label updates correctly... This does the job but it's annoying that this is the best solution I've found so far. I'm currently figuring out the minimum amount of time I need to sleep the thread for... 1 second was not long enough.

Comment: Have you tried clicking "Refresh" in your Windows Explorer (or press "F5")?

Comment: @knittl Yes, refreshing or even closing and reopening file explorer doesn't show the new drive label

Comment: See if you get on any better with Powershell `New-PSDrive`

Comment: When you execute the unmount command, do you wait for it to complete before remounting? In other words, do you call [`waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) on the `Process` object?

Comment: Please check the windows registry HKEY_USERS/<Your user S-1-...>/Network/<Letter> after you executed the mount via Java. It may well be that you are lacking some Windows authorization to update the registry from a non-system process and restarting Explorer forces a reenumeration of all mappings and thus "correcting" the registry entries.

Comment: @D.Kovács *"It may well be that you are lacking some Windows authorization"* Why would it work from the command line then?

Comment: @D.Kovács In my second update I was able to get it working if I `sleep()` a few seconds between unmounting and mounting. Wouldn't this indicate it isn't a permissions issue?

Comment: @Olivier: Fair enough, my thinking was along the lines that maybe the OS is somehow handling subprocesses spawned via cmd/powershell differently than a process started from another parent (Java in this case).

Comment: @rhowell: In that case could you check whether without sleep and with sleep the registry entries are incorrect/correct? My next bet is that the process has to stay alive until the registry updates are done in the background by the OS. This would also mean that you will never achieve a consistent "minimum time" needed for the sleep.

Comment: @D.Kovács Note that the OP still didn't say if they were calling `waitFor()` or not.

Comment: @Olivier @D.Kovács I've just tested `waitFor()` and it doesn't appear to work unfortunately. Also, strangely enough the drive is not appearing at all in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Network` even though other network drives are visible there. I can't find it anywhere under `HKEY_USERS` either. I have tested this with both `sleep()` and without `sleep()`.

Comment: @D.Kovács I was able to find a bunch of the drives i've mapped under ```HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ Explorer\MountPoints2\``` but here in the registry it doesnt show any labels or what letter the drive is mapped to

Comment: @Olivier @D.Kovács I should have also mentioned that the `waitFor()` executed very quickly, much faster than the 2.5-3 seconds that I need to `sleep()` in order for the label to update. Maybe there is some underlying OS process that isn't tied to my java process?

Comment: @rhowell: The registry path you are looking for is `HKEY_USERS\S-<many-numbers-like-1-5-21-...looooooong-number-with-dashes...>\Network\<letter of drive>`. The field `RemotePath` in this registry entry shows the currently mapped path for this user behind this drive letter.

Comment: @D.Kovács Yea I looked through every one of those entries and I can see the other network drives there but not the one I am mapping at all.

Comment: In that case I'll write that up as an answer. My understanding is that the process triggers a registry update, which is not finished in case the process that triggered it is killed/finished. Thus the "proper" solution would be to keep the Java process alive until the mapping is available.

Answer (score 1):

Windows keeps the mapping of label to network locations for the current user in the registry, cf. [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/a/986714/604002).

Apparently—based on the discussion in comments on the question—there is some kind of interaction between the spawned process being stopped and the registry update not finishing fully. I.e., the process creates the mapping, which triggers an update in the registry, but if the process terminates before the registry update is finished, the registry update is cancelled (or maybe not even invoked? It may be that in order it to be invoked, the process handle, which created the mapping still has to be there for the internal OS trigger).

Thus, the "proper" solution is not a `waitFor()` (as it does not work), or a `sleep(n)` (because there is no realiable way to tell for any `n` that it will work, because of OS scheduling). The "proper" solution is to keep the process alive and check whether the registry update happens (i.e., the label is registered and available) and when it has been finished, then you can close the process.

Of course, pragmatically speaking, a `sleep(10_000);` should do the trick, you are just wasting some negligible amount of CPU cycles and RAM.